# If eddy currents are generated in superconductor what would happen if ..?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, electric-current, superconductivity, electromagnetic-induction

Eddy currents are generated in a conducting sheet when it oscillates in a uniform B field. It is stated in books that the sheet will show damping, as in the setup below:

[image]

So, I want to ask if I placed a superconductor in place of the metal sheet, will it show damping or not?

I am ready to explain more if needed, please let me know.

Comment: Couple of comments. First, you should either be asking for a resource or asking a physics question. Second, it's a rule of technical writing that you should write out abbreviations—at the very least write them out the first time so that everyone is on the same page; I'm *guessing* that you mean "emi" to stand in for "electromagnetic induction", but ... when a physic professor has to guess the abbreviation to too localized to be good style in addressing a general audience. Your best bet in the short term would be to ask in [the h bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar).

Comment: Pardon me for small mistakes I made .is it okay now

Comment: I suppose it won't move at all, as eddy currents, once generated, in a superconductor would not die down and hence sustain it in its position.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the conducting sheet with a superconductor and release the superconductor from some initial displacement where there is no magnetic field, then the superconductor moves until it has established eddy currents that exactly cancel the local external magnetic field. The superconducting pendulum slows to a halt before it reaches the rest position of the conducting pendulum. It levitates with some finite displacement from rest because the eddy currents persist. Since it does not return to its rest position, the superconducting pendulum does not show [damping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_ratio) in the same sense as the conducting pendulum.

Comment: But why it is coming to halt or slowing down ....... thats what I want to ask??... Like who is making it to stop .. there should not be any energy loss and is there is what it is ??

Comment: The external magnetic field is cancelled inside the superconductor with eddy currents (called Meissner effect). The eddy currents establish a magnetic dipole field ($\mu$) outside of the superconductor, which interacts with the steep gradient of the uniform magnetic field at the edge of the plate ($\nabla B$), with the force $F=\mu \nabla B$. This is the force that causes the pendulum to slow down and come to a halt. The kinetic energy of the pendulum is converted into magnetic field energy ($V=\mu B$).